# python with adding commas and pythagorean

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def FuncE():
    for x in range(1,11):
        print str(2*x-1) + ",",


def FuncF():
    n = 7
    c = "1"
    for x in range(0, 9-1):
        print str(x*c) + ', ',


def FuncG():
    for a in range(1,51):
       for b in range(a + 1,51):
           for c in range(b + 1,51):
               if (a*a + b*b == c*c):
                       print  "\t\t\t",a,b,c
```

im using  idle (python GUI) then making worked in  python (command line)

for FuncE
need to print 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19 but when i try it it cames out like 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19, with a extra comma

i need FuncF to print out 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111 but the problem here is that it cames out ,1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111, and i don't wanted a comma begin or at end. i need them be taken off.

then for the FuncG
im trying to make it worked by using the Pythagorean numbers but only using one "if" command
and also don't wanted to have same numbers appear twice in the column when comes out
when i try it cames out:

3 4 5

4 3 5

5 12 13

6 8 10

7 13 17

8 6 10

. . .

. . .

and so on

Comment: I think I *maybe* understand what you want for `FuncF`, but I am completely lost for what you want for `FuncG`.  Can you explain more?

Comment: Also, in the `for` loop where you are trying to add the commas, what is the purpose of the `c` variable?  To me, it looks like the code will repeat the number `"1"` multiple times depending on the current value of `x`, which is not the output you say you are getting.

Comment: in FuncG wanted to repeated numbers like 3 4 5 then down  4 3 5  then 5 12 13 and so on but don't wanted the numbers to appear twice in one column

Comment: i need FuncF to print out 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111

Comment: But that's not what you said in the original question!!!!!  You said you wanted "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"!!!!!

Comment: im using idle (python GUI) then making worked in python (command line) for FuncE need to print 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19 but when i try it it cames out like 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19, with a extra comma

i need FuncF to print out 1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111 but the problem here is that it cames out ,1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 111111, 1111111, and i don't wanted a comma begin or at end. i need them be taken off.

Comment: then for the FuncG im trying to make it worked by using the Pythagorean numbers but only using one "if" command and also don't wanted to have same numbers appear twice in the column when comes out when i try it cames out: 3 4 5 4 3 5 5 12 13 6 8 10 7 13 17 8 6 10

Answer (score 0):

```
def odd_numbers(n):
    return ','.join([str(2*i-1) for i in range(1,n)])


def groups_of_ones(n):
    return ','.join([str("1"*i) for i in range(1,n)])


def pythagorean_numbers(n):
    import itertools
    all_groups = set([])
    for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(range(1,b)):
        group = tuple(sorted([a,b,c]))
        if a*a + b*b == c*c and group not in all_groups:
            all_groups.add(group)
    return all_groups

print odd_numbers(11) # prints 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19
print groups_of_ones(8) # prints 1,11,111,1111,11111,111111,1111111
for a,b,c in pythagorean_numbers(51):
    print "\t\t\t", a, b, c
```

In this answer, I have shown you the `join` method of python strings (look up "python string join" on google for more help).  This does what you were trying to do in FuncE and FuncF.

I also renamed your functions to names that describe the function (called self-documentation).

I also added a set in the pythagorean function to store the previously seen groups of numbers. I also showed you the `itertools.combinations` function, which is an easier way to do the triple loop your were doing.  With this method you probably don't need the `and group not in all_groups` that I added, but I did it to show you how to make sure you haven't already seen that group of numbers.

Last, instead of printing within the function, I have returned the values created by the function.

Answer (score -1):

Can you print the string once it's complete?

```
my_string = ""
   for x in range(0, 9-1):
      my_string += str(x)
      if x != 7:
         my_string += ", "
print my_string
```

When you print something using a comma character after the object of `print`, python automatically inserts a space. If you want to get around this, you need to print a string all at once, use string interpolation, or something similar.

You need to be a little bit clearer with the `FuncG` portion of your question, I'm not understanding the issue you have.

Comment: I'm confused, where did the `if x not 7` come from?  I don't think that does what you think it does anyway... I'm sure you mean `if x != 7`

Comment: Wouldn't `my_string = ','.join([str(x*c) for x in range(0,9-1)])` be more concise and clearer?  Still, given that `c="1"` that will print out ",1,11,111,1111,1111,etc..." which is not what the OP wants based on his question.

Comment: This was a simple way to avoid adding a trailing comma at the end of the loop, but could definitely be more elegant.

*edit:* good point, and of course that would be nicer. I just left "c" in because the original code had it, but looking now I'm not clear what it's function was meant to be...

Comment: The simplest way is to use the `.join` method that is built into the language.  Either way, your code is not syntactically correct.  It has indentation errors and `x not 7` returns a `SyntaxError`.  Did you test the code out before posting it?